# GWT Remote Debugging

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to do a remote debug session for my GWT app.

I added an entry in the GWT plugin running on a Firefox instance in the remote machine:

```
Host Name   | Code Server
[IP address] [127.0.0.1]
```

However, I'm am still not able to access the GWT app even though I can ping the IP address with the specific port: `8888`

Any ideas?

Comment: I've done this before, but I am quite unsure as to why it doesn't work now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you right you're trying to connect your client to the remote server and debug client? I'm always debugging using Eclipse IDE. So:

- you run debug mode in your Eclipse.
- put in your browser url like
  http://remotedomain.com:8888/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 where
  gwt.codesvr is your local(!) machine.

Now, you are able to talk to the remote server, but your client-side code is from inside your machine. You can use all power of the Eclipse to debug.

Hope this will help you.